# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (10054):paramiko

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, automation, paramiko

I am running an automation suite which is giving this error after some iteration

```
stdin,stdout,stderr = self.ssh.exec_command('uname')
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 472, in exec_command

    chan = self._transport.open_session(timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 765, in open_session
    timeout=timeout)

  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 852, in open_channel
    raise SSHException('SSH session not active')

paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: SSH session not active
```

Comment: What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: I searched for solutions but haven't got any.